# Does the order of defining a variable and using it matters in Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm a little confused of the behavior of Makefile while working on a mini project. In Makefile, when I have

```
all: $(TARGETS)

TARGETS = stats

....
```

the make command gives "make: Nothing to be done for `all'."

When I declare the TARGETS before using it:

```
TARGETS = stats
all: $(TARGETS)
....
```

the make command compiles and works as expected.

It seems the order of defining a variable and calling that variable matters here.

But later I find:

```
stats: LDLIBS+=$(STATS_LIBS)
STATS_LIBS = -lm
```

and

```
STATS_LIBS = -lm
stats: LDLIBS+=$(STATS_LIBS)
```

both work and give the right behavior, so it seems the order does not matter anymore? How should I understand this?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing two distinct effects.

1. Expansion of a reference to a macro for which currently there is no definition yields an empty string.  That fully explains your `TARGETS` case.
2. By default, macro references in a macro's body are not expanded until the macro is used.  Thus, supposing that `LDLIBS` is a macro with this behavior, when `make` processes `LDLIBS+=$(STATS_LIBS)`, it adds the literal characters `$(STATS_LIBS)` to the value of `LDLIBS`.  It expands that only when a reference to `LDLIBS` is expanded, using the definition of `STATS_LIBS` relevant at that time.